# help with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, abnt

I'm Brazilian, Humanities researcher, and I'm using the `biblatex-abnt` version with the `abnt-ibid` option (loads both the *citestyle* and the *bibstyle*).
In the biblatex package manual (and also in the biblatex-abnt manual) it says that the *first reference* **always** appears "complete" (full).
Is there any way to modify this?
I would like to omit some fields in the reference notes (in my case, footnotes), such as DOI, ISBN, ISSN, URL... but I wanted all the information *to remain at the end*, where the bibliography appears.
Is there a way to omit some fields *only in the notes*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\AtEveryCitekey` hook to execute arbitrary code for each citation. With `\clearfield` we can delete the fields we don't want. (Keep in mind that what is colloquially called a "field" by most people can be of three different types for `biblatex`: literal fields, literal lists and name lists. Those are deleted with `\clearfield`, `\clearlist` and `\clearname`, respectively. You can find the type of each field in the `biblatex` documentation.)

For DOI, URL, ISBN and ISSN you'd need

```
\documentclass[brazilian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=abnt-ibid]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{url}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{issn}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{worman}
sit \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: SIGFRIDSSON, Emma; RYDE, Ulf. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, v. 19, n. 4, p. 377–395, 1998.]